# How to drop element from a list inside a pandas column in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a column in a dataframe that contain a list inside. My dataframe column is:

```
 [],
 ['NORM'],
 ['NORM'],
 ['NORM'],
 ['NORM'],
 ['MI', 'STTC'],
```

As you can see I have an empty list and also a list with two elements. How can I change list with two elements to just take one of it (I don't care which one of it).
I tried with `df.column.explode()`but this just add more rows and I don't want more rows, I just need to take one of it.
Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with a custom mapping function which maps the elements of column according to desired requirements:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].map(lambda l: l[:1])
```

Result:

```
# print(df['col'])

0        []
1    [NORM]
2    [NORM]
3    [NORM]
4    [NORM]
5      [MI]
```

Answer (score 1):

i, j is the location of the cell you need to access and this will give the first element of the list

```py
list_ = df.loc[i][j]
if len(list_) > 0:
   print(list_[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

As you store lists into a pandas column, I assume that you do not worry for vectorization. So you could just use a list comprehension:

```
df[col] = [i[:1] for i in df[col]]
```